# Talking to the build window from source code (GNU compiler)

Tags: c, gnu

Is it possible to pass a message to the GNU build window from the source code?
Something like:

foo.c  (not a makefile)

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   Echo "The Debug flag is set"

// more code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the diagnostic pragmas in gcc:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

e.g.

> GCC also offers a simple mechanism for printing messages during compilation.
>
>  `#pragma message string`
>     Prints string as a compiler message on compilation. The message is informational only, and is neither a compilation warning nor an error.

```
          #pragma message "Compiling " __FILE__ "..."
```